# multi class multi label CNN but not every image will have multi labels

Tags: conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I want to classify images that can have some images with more than one class but not all. An example: if there are images with just shirts, images with just pants, and images that show shirts and pants. If the CNN outputs a label only of shirts for an image that shows both shirts and pants, I would like that to be counted as a correct label. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried a CNN for multiclassification on my data with 15 labels and I get 83.5 accuracy. The problem is that images of clothing sometimes show a model from the waist up wearing a shirt, but in other images, the full model is shown and therefore wearing both a shirt and pants. However, some times it is difficult to see the pants in the full model. (I am giving a very simple example here. There are scarves and numerous other pieces of clothing that are sometimes shown with other pieces of clothing.) I do not thing that image segmentation will work here because because the images are not clear enough for that.